# Царь Дадон

Tags: литература, ономастика

У Пушкина в "Золотом петушке" фигурирует царь Дадон. Пушкин вообще давал царям в сказках интересные имена. И вот любопытно, это имя - просто набор букв или оно имеет какое-то значение?
Буду благодарен за версии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну какой же Дадон - разумный?

перессорился со всеми, с молодости жадный был и наглый, а к старости затупел настолько, что не мог ориентироваться во внешнеполитических своих делах. Словом - дадон :)

Comment: Вы, видимо, судите по опере "Золотой петушок" Римского-Корсако, где Дадон изображен не в лучшем свете. У Пушкина же читаем, что Дадон "смолоду был грозен он // И соседям то и дело // Наносил обиды смело". Это был грозный и успешный государь, все "проблемы" начались под старость.

Comment: Воинственность  - это еще не разумность. Надо было не ссориться с соседями, а развивать торговлю и промышленность, тогда к старости и проблем было бы поменьше. Смелость и храбрость тоже не всегда одно и то же. Смелый - это еще и дерзкий, а иногда и нескромный. В общем, не конструктивный был этот Дадон, за что и поплатился.

Comment: Если бы он был не разумным, то царство у него было с гулькин нос, хилое, голодное, нищее. Но у Пушкина видно, что его царство процветает. Наличие соседей, которые хотят откусить кусок — это не следствие неконструктивности, а обычное явление для того времени. Средневековые междоусобицы — "это норма" (с).

 А в чем разница между смелостью и храбростью? Я коннотации "нескромный" у "смелого" не вижу совсем.

Comment: Территория, действительно, неплохая - всё-таки восемь дней пешего хода, это сколько в километрах будет! Наверное, по наследству ему досталась. И по поводу смелости/храбрости. Храбрость - это внутреннее свойство человека, его потенциальная способность преодолеть страх. А смелость - это, скорее, решительность, иногда граничащая с безрассудством (уже отрицательное качество). И из словаря: СМЕЛЫЙ. 4.
Выходящий за границы принятого; нескромный. С-ая поза. С-ые манеры. С-ое одеяние. С-ая шутка.

Comment: Мне понравилась ссылка Софии на статью о возможном происхождении сказки. И все же, осталась неясность: "Царица, вдруг, пропала". Она ли была врагом-завоевателем, о котором кричал золотой петух? Она пропала - как чары. А чары - дело чародея. А чародей в этой истории умер от руки Дадона. То есть, девица-чаровница  - дело рук старика, принесшего Дадону золотого петуха... Тут я - в ступоре. В чем мораль?

Answer (score 5):

> > ДАДОН — муж., влад. неуклюжий, нескладный, несуразный человек.

Словарь Даля.

Выбор имени кажется странным, ведь Дадон у Пушкина был достаточно бравым и разумным государем в молодости.

Comment: Не был он разумным. Наносить обиды соседям - совершенно не разумное поведение, что и подчёркивается выбором имени. Потом он: дал необдуманное обещание; отказался его выполнять; поссорился с мудрецом, оказавшим ему большую услугу; избил его. Молодец топ

Comment: Наносить обиды соседям, отбирая у них земли и обременяя данью, во все времена считалось успехом. Всё остальное он сделал уже в пожилом возрасте, а со стариков спрос другой.

Answer (score 2):

(1)Сюжет сказки взят Пушкиным у В.  Ирвинга из «Легенды об арабском звездочете» 
 (1832).  В основу изложенной Ирвингом арабской легенды легли предания о великом древнеримском поэте Вергилии, за которым молва упрочила славу мага и чародея. Легенды гласят, что Вергилий воздвиг в Риме роскошный дворец, где были установлены статуи, олицетворявшие все области, подвластные Риму, каждая с деревянным колоколом в руке. Когда в какой-нибудь из областей возникала опасность, тотчас соответствующая статуя начинала звонить в колокол. Тогда же на вершине
дворца появлялся медный всадник и,  потрясая копьем, оборачивался в ту
сторону, откуда грозила беда...

(2)Этот сюжет был переосмыслен Пушкиным и связан с   «Повестью о Бове Королевиче», где фигурирует король Дадон. Нарицательное значение — неуклюжий, нескладный человек. Повесть восходит к средневековому французскому роману о подвигах рыцаря Бово д’Антона. На Русь эта повесть попала сложным путем — через славянский перевод итальянской версии романа, сделанный в Дубровнике в XVI веке. Все русские и белорусские списки повести восходят к этому не сохранившемуся переводу. Из всех рыцарских и авантюрных произведений, бытовавших на Руси в допетровское время, повесть о Бове пользовалась наибольшим успехом. Известно около 100 рукописей и около 200 лубочных изданий. Действие лубочного «Бовы» происходит «в некоем царстве, в славном городе Антоне» и в нескольких соседних царствах. Сам герой — сын «антонского,короля», который был предательски убит его братом царем Дадоном по наущению своей жены Милитрисы Кирбитьевны (сходство с сюжетом шекспировского "Гамлета").

(3) Не случайно поэт назвал царя этим именем: слово «дадон» означает «неуклюжий, нескладный, несуразный человек»; оно встречается в народной речии вошло в «Толковый словарь»  В.И. Даля.  Дадоном называл Пушкин и злого, жестокого царя-деспота в сказочной поэме «Бова», написанной им в годы пребывания в лицее. В «Сказке о золотом петушке» царь Дадон изображен ярко и колоритно. Саркастически именуемый «славным», а на деле ленивый и скудоумный, он проводит все время в сладостной дремоте, а с подданными разговаривает зевая. Монарх, дремлющий на троне!

http://www.school2100.ru/upload/iblock/d8a/d8a641e2935a0c094736521c47dd69cd.pdf